# jQuery accordion, header links and saved state

Tags: jquery, accordion

I'm using jquery ui accordion and want to have links on the headers, and for it save the menu state once the header link is clicked.
At the moment I can only get one to work without the other. (No links and saved state or links and no saved state)
I am very much a jquery beginner so any help is greatly appreciated.

Nav setup:

```
<nav class="main-nav">
    <ul id="menu-main">
        <li><a href="http://home/">Home</a></li>
        <li>
            <a class="accord" href="http://link1/">Header with link</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="http://link2/">Link2</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://link3/">Link3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul> 
</nav>
```

Accordion setup:

```
$(".main-nav > ul" ).accordion({
    active: false,
    heightStyle: "content",
    header: "> li > a.accord",
    clearStyle: true,
    collapsible: true,
    navigation: true       
});

$(".main-nav > ul > li > a").click(function() {
    window.location = $(this).attr('href');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: What's the point in having those links in the header? If you click the link you'll get directed to the new page, right?

Comment: Yes you will get redirected to a new page. I want the menu to be open on that new page.
It's just a fail safe really. I will be implementing it into a wordpress site and I just want to give the client the option rather than tell them they can't do it.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jquery-vertical-accordion-menu/

Comment: I have come across this, but I would like to avoid having my main site navigation run by a plugin.
Thanks for the suggestion though.